# How to get print statement in xpinc?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotusscript, xpinc

I've successfully created a view in XPages which contains list of all my lotusscript agents and a button to run the selected agent. When I select any one of the agent and run it, it successfully run but all the print statements are not appearing. I checked my code and my print codes are there. Run my agent from designer and the print statements do appear. Is this due to the limitation of xpinc?

Comment: Have you checked log.nsf on the server to see if the agent print statements are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print statements go to the console. So you should find them in the log.nsf you also can start the client with the -rparams -console to get a console. Of course you could follow [this example](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SF7AH) and send the print to a place where you can process it.
Or - if the prints serve debugging purposes, use the [Debug Toolbar](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPage%20Debug%20Toolbar) from OpenNTF.